# What is wrong with calculating the Z-score?

Tags: pandas, indexing

I'm following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba) on removing outliers. I have a train and a test set:

```
train.shape
>>>(38959, 114)
test.shape
>>>(3988, 114)
```

I have:

```
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(train.astype(float)))
train = train[(z < 3).all(axis=1)]

z_ = np.abs(stats.zscore(test.astype(float)))
test = test[(z_ < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

This will work just fine for `train`, but will remove every single row in test. No matter if I do `test[(z_ < 3).all(axis=1)]` or `test[(z_ > 3).all(axis=1)]` it will always return an empty dataframe. Why on earth could this happen? Both dataframes have been encoded the same way and have the exact same number of columns. Only the number of rows is different.

Comment: `z_` is somehow getting all `nan`.  `test` probably has `nan` in it so when you zscore, you get `nan`.  Then `z_ > 3` or `z_ < 3` are both `False`.  That's my guess.

Comment: It's not nan, if I print `z_` it actually contains a bunch of numbers less than 3. And there's no nan in my sets either as I imputed them.

Comment: Then you'd need to provide a sample data set that reproduces the problem so I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced this trouble too.
Found out that if your dataframe columns has non-unique value
(For example the column full of categorial value of 1). If it's true then **stats.zscore** turns this column into NaN values. Then np.abs just turns it to True.

The reason is you have to fillna before "np.abs()"

**I found following solution:**

```
z_scores = pd.DataFrame(stats.zscore(df))
z_scores.fillna(0, inplace=True)
z_scores = np.abs(z_scores < 3).all(axis=1)
filtered_df = df[z_scores]
```

For better data representation, we can cut outliers only for continious values such as income, salary. e.t.c